# Why is the equalizer of $\mathsf{Set}$ as it is?

Tags: category-theory

The definition of equalizer from Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equaliser_(mathematics)

I read the definition of equaliser, but I can't use it to find the equalizer of $\mathsf{Set}$.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: There is no deductive reasoning in a definition. It is very unclear what you are trying to ask here. Please try to improve your question.

Comment: using of definition (general) to "calculate" the equalizer of a (specific) example, category(Set). How??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect that what you are asking is, "Why is $E_{f, g}=\{x: f(x)=g(x)\}$ the equalizer *in the sense of category theory* of $f$ and $g$, in the category of sets?"

Well, first of all, it's not *exactly* the same. Remember that in category theory, the equalizer is an object *together with a certain map*. In this case, since $E_{f, g}$ is a subset of the domain $X$, it's natural to expect this arrow to be the inclusion map. So the right question to ask is:

> Why is $E_{f, g}$, together with the inclusion map $\alpha: E_{f, g}\subseteq X$, the category-theoretic equalizer of $f$ and $g$ in the category of sets?

*And really, since an arrow specifies its domain and codomain, the equalizer can be taken to be just $\alpha$ itself.*

We first need to show that $f\circ \alpha=g\circ \alpha$. This is easy: $f(\alpha(x))=f(x)$ and $g(\alpha(x))=g(x)$, but for $x\in E_{f, g}$ we have $f(x)=g(x)$.

Now the more interesting part is showing that $\alpha$ satisfies a universal property: that whenever I have a map $m: A\rightarrow X$ such that $f\circ m=g\circ m$, there is a unique $i: A\rightarrow E_{f, g}$ with $\alpha\circ i=m$.

The idea here is that $m$ has to have image in $E_{f, g}$ (this should be clear from the assumption on $m$), and this provides a natural map $i$ from $A$ to $E_{f, g}$; set-theoretically this map is the same as $m$, but since arrows specify their domain and codomain in category theory, these are different arrows. Now we have $$(\alpha\circ i)(x)=m(x),$$ since $i$ sends $x$ to $m(x)$ (it's the same as $m$ except that it has a different codomain: $E_{f, g}$ instead of $X$) and $\alpha$ sends $x$ to $x$ (again, $\alpha$ is set-theoretically the identity on $E_{f, g}$, but it's a different arrow since it has a different codomain: $X$ instead of $E_{f, g}$).

So we've shown that $\alpha$ makes the relevant diagram commute, and is universal in this sense; and that's just the definition of the category-theoretic equalizer!

---

Note that above I kept talking about "the" equalizer in the category-theoretic sense. This isn't actually good practice - really, this notion is only defined *up to isomorphism* (and this is true of most notions in category theory - indeed, non-isomorphism-invariant notions are often considered [evil](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/principle+of+equivalence)!). So throw the words "up to isomorphism" into the answer above, a whole bunch of times, if this is something you want to be explicit about.

---

Note that in the move from the specific category of sets to general category theory, we add a piece of data that's "trivial" in the set-theoretic context: the inclusion map $\alpha: E_{f, g}\subseteq X$. This is a common theme in category theory: we realize that the object itself isn't as important as how it relates to the other things we're considering, and this causes us to see arrows that were implicit in the picture but must be made explicit to generalize the definition appropriately.

Comment: To the editor: I believe "$\alpha\circ i$" is correct: it is a map from $A$ to $X$, it first goes from $A$ to $E_{f, g}$ via $i$, and then goes from $E_{f, g}$ to $X$ via $\alpha$; so this is $\alpha\circ i$.

Comment: for the existance of $i$, can i say that: because $A, E_{f,g}$ exists as sets$\Rightarrow$$A\times E_{f,g}$ exist as set$\Rightarrow$exist $i\subseteq A\times  E_{f,g}$??

Comment: i can't edit the previously comment: exist $i\subseteq  A\times E_{f,g}$ with the property $a\circ i=m$. if $i$ is not unique there exist $i'$ such that $a\circ i'=m$. so $a\circ i=a\circ i'$, but $a$ as inclusion is injective so is monomorphism, so $a\circ i=a\circ i'\Rightarrow i=i'$